# Terminal stimulation

Tags: forms, input, digits

Am very nēw to JavaScript and I want to develop a terminal website like baba ijebu which is commonly use to stake bet in my locals I have actually gotten the logic but the problem is how to make the digital number stay in two and two (eg 01 09 56 67 45) in this form is the problem I have tried form tag and input method of different style still don't get it

Input method and form tag telephone number style 2digit {0-99}2/s

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.